# How do I pass a data member name as a parameter for use on another parameter?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameter-passing, generic-programming

Given a struct such as this:

```
struct Foo{
    std::string name;
    int value;
};
```

I'm looking for a way to pass both the instantiation of the type,
as well as the data member name,
each as separate arguments.

Although this is incorrect syntax, I think it helps illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
template<typename MemberName>
void Print(Foo foo, MemberName member_name){
    std::cout << foo.member_name << '\n';  
}

int main(){

    Foo foo{"name",100}; //create instance

    Print(foo,.name);  //prints name
    Print(foo,.value); //prints 100
}
```

How can this be achieved in C++?

Additionally, I do not have access to modify the deceleration of the type.

Comment: Hmm.. might be me being stupid here but what does "ADT" mean in this context?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like C#'s reflection...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An abstract data type.  Anything that can have a data member.  A struct or a class.  Not one of the fundamental types of the language.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: We call them "user-defined types" in C++. Or, y'know, classes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the term user-defined type applies to enumerations as well, and enumerations can't have data members.  Looking back on my question though, ADT is probably misleading terminology for the C++ lexicon, so I'll change my question to use 'struct' instead of ADT.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: Interestingly, I can't find a normative definition for "user-defined type". Enumerations are, like classes (including unions) and pointers and arrays and so forth, compound types at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for pointers to members:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
  std::string name;
  int value;
};

template<typename MemberType>
void Print(Foo foo, MemberType Foo::* member_name){
  std::cout << foo.*member_name << '\n';  
}

int main(){

  Foo foo{"name",100}; //create instance

  Print(foo, &Foo::name);  //prints name
  Print(foo, &Foo::value); //prints 100
}
```

Edit: of course, pointers to members aren't really common in c++ and in this specific case, just passing the actual member values like Steephen suggests is better (but maybe you want to use them in a more complicated case)